# How to access a Spring MVC model attribute name that contain a dot in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Well, since Spring Boot framework recommend the Thymeleaf template engine, so I've created a simple project with `Web` and `Thymeleaf` dependencies selected using http://start.spring.io.

As the following `HomeController` and `home/about.html` template works fine.

This is the java source code for `HomeController`:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home/about")
    public String about(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "About");
        return "home/about";
    }
}
```

And this is the html source code for `home/about.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Test for dot!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${title}">H1Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

As I change the model attribute name **with some dot** like `home.about.title` with the full code as below:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home/about")
    public String about(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("home.about.title", "About");
        return "home/about";
    }
}
```

And the html code becomes as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Test for dot!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${home.about.title}">H1Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Well, some errors occur, and that's confusing!

So, what's the matter with **dot** in model attribute name? Is it a special character for reserved usage? And how to make it works?

I've searched in StackOverflow and find a similar question [How to access a Spring MVC model attribute name that contain a dot in Freemarker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379151/how-to-access-a-spring-mvc-model-attribute-name-that-contain-a-dot-in-freemarker), but the answer in that question can't apply to Thymeleaf.

Comment: Not the expert on this, but I would think thymeleaf is looking for the attribute "home" with a field "about", itself with a subfield "title". As if you'd done `model.addAttribute("home", new Home(new About("title")));`

Comment: @alexbt Well, I have the same idea, but I can't find any official documentation specifying that limitation or ambiguous usage. Actually, I even don't know whether `home.about.title` is best practice for text distinction.

Comment: When you use the dots in the attribute name, you are using a key character, then in your view thymeleaf think the object "home" have and attribute called "about" and this also have a final attribute called "title" which is not true, thats why is failing. As some colleague said, use i18 internazionalization

Answer (score 3):

The dot is used to refer to attributes/methods of objects.  When you have the expression `${home.about.title}` it is attempting to find a model object `home` and call `home.getAbout().getTitle()`.  I've been able to get around this by doing something like this

```
<!-- thymeleaf 2 -->
<span th:text="${#vars.get('home.about.title')}" />

<!-- thymeleaf 3 -->
<span th:text="${#vars.getVariable('home.about.title')}" />
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.  You should really stay away from using the dot character in model attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to work with internationalized messages like this.

For Spring Boot project create file messages.properties (messages_cs.properties etc.) in **src/main/resources/**

And content of **src/main/resources/messages.properties** will be

```
home.about.title=About
```

And then in Thymeleaf you'll use hashtag instead of dollar.

```
<h1 th:text="#{home.about.title}">H1Title</h1>
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, however, you may miss the point. The question is not about internationalized message and I just want to know how to access model attribute name contain a dot in Thymeleaf.

Comment: Well I don't think it's possible due to fact that it would collide with calling methods on instances of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If these aren't just "messages" that need internationalization, or you can't follow the standard convention, I think the best way is to create a class that contains the properties you want. For example, the Properties class is built in (since JDK 7 I believe).

In your controller:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("my.key", "my.value");
model.add(props, "Properties");
```

Then, in your template:

```
<span th:text="${Properties.getProperty('my.key')}" />
```

Of course, you can create your own wrapper class and change the method name to make access more convenient so the end result might be more like:

```
<span th:text="${Store.get('my.key')}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requested attribute name is with a dot, you may access it through the implicit HttpServletRequest object. For example:

```
${#request.getAttribute('javax.servlet.error.exception')}
```